# Defining what a proposition is is in propositional logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

What is an exact definition of a proposition that we can use to apply to sentences in natural language? Are the following propositions?

1.) "I am calling you a liar."

2.) "4 is the square root of twelve." 
Is twelve really defined as it could be the number 12 with any radix or be a variable named "twelve" - how do we know?

Comment: Do you really insist upon "natural language" with propositional logic ? Then I'm afraid you will face some problems ..

Comment: So then for 1. and 2. are they propositions or we cannot know?

Comment: I've only suggested that the joint venture (propositional logic - natural language) will turn out to be somewhat problematic in due time. Read this classic one from Alfred Tarski: http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/QED/if_then.htm .

Comment: My personal opinion is that for logic & mathematics, we don't need to know what a proposition is. It's just something which is either true or false (or maybe lacks a truth-value, depending on our logic). The question of what a proposition is, is a philosophical one that's been argued about interminably. See [http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/propositions/]

Answer (score 1):

According to Quine, is better to avoid speaking of *propositions*, because of their "ontological committment".

The link between logic and language is through *sentences* i.e. expressions of natural language.

Propositional logic is formalized using "sentential" variables ($p$ , $q$, ...): so you must call it *sentential logic*.

Of course, in philosophy you will meet again propositions (e.g. with the issue regarding truth-bearer).