# Is the "parallel axiom" sentence, a proposition in absolute geometry?

Tags: propositional-calculus, axiomatic-geometry

I will try to explain in other words. Given a formal theory of absolute geometry, we are able to write the expression whose meaning is the paralel axiom.

The question is, that expression is a "proposition"? AFAIK a "proposition" in propositional logic is a "thing" that is true or false. It cannot be undecided.

On the other side, we can add this expression as an axiom and we will have euclidean geometry.

Now I guess there is no issue to consider that these expression is a proposition.

Probably I need some precise definitions of what a proposition is, what a predicate is, what an axiom is, how a language is defined, ...

Comment: As you pointed out i suggest you to learn some logic before dealing with such questions. You will find that your stated question is reduced to find alternative (but equivalent) set of axioms for a theory.

Comment: Any link where it is clearly expressed the diference between expresions and propositions?

Comment: You have to consider the difference between a proposition in prop logic and a sntence in natural language.

Comment: In the formal language of *predicate logic* we call *sentence* a formula with no free variables, like $\forall x (x=x)$

Comment: If we formalize elementary geometry with the language of predicate calculus, the axioms are sentences.

Comment: In formalized mathematical theories we may have undecidable sentences.

Comment: "If we formalize elementary geometry with the language of predicate calculus, the axioms are sentences." Given this particular elementary geometry formalized with the language of predicate calculus, is any axiom a proposition too? "A1 v A2" (meaning axiom1 or axioms2) is a sentence? Is it true? Is a proposition?

Comment: A sentence of a formalized theory has a definite truth value in each interpretation; changing interpretation, the truth value may change. Consider the sentence expressibg "there ate two objects": it will be false in some interpretation and true in other.

Comment: And yes, axioms are true in the models of the theory.

Comment: "A sentence of a formalized theory has a definite truth value in each interpretation". Then the sentence "paralell axiom" (there is one single line that goes throught this point and doesn't cross this given line) in a formalized theory of absolute geometry has a definite truth value? Sorry to insist... I don't see what I am doing wrong...

Comment: If we consider the parallel postulate and we interpret it in the physical space of everyday experience, it holds. If we interpret in the cosmic space of general relativity, it does not.

Comment: An interpretation must decide the truth value of any sentence (including the undecidable ones)?

Comment: Truth is about the relationship between language and world: we expect that a statement **has** a definite truth value in the world (the model of the theory). But this does not imply that the axioms and the underlying logic are sufficient to formally prove (or disprove) it.

Comment: The parallel postulate is independent of [Absolute geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_geometry) (i.e. undecidable) because we have models of absolute geometry where the parallel postulate holds (Euclidean gem) and others where it does not (non-Euclidean geom) [we have already discussed it above].

Comment: See [Formal definition of proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795307/formal-definition-of-proposition) and [Sentence vs proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232232/sentence-vs-proposition) as well as [Defining what a proposition is is in propositional logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/606769/defining-what-a-proposition-is-is-in-propositional-logic)

Comment: See also [What is the difference between a statement and proposition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687016/what-is-the-difference-between-a-statement-and-proposition) as well as [Is "This sentence is true" a proposition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671517/is-this-sentence-is-true-true-or-false-or-both-is-it-a-proposition)

Comment: "Truth is about the relationship between language and world: we expect that a statement has a definite truth value in the world (the model of the theory)." If I believe that in my world a statement could remain unverificable forever (neither true nor false) should I ban clasical propositional calculus and replace it with Kleene three valued logic for example? And then think about a predicate calculus that follows Kleene logic etc etc... If I do that, provability and thruth could become equivalent again? (like my oldself before reading about Godel, Cantor and so on...)

Comment: In fact in quantum mechanics, the position and the momentum of a particle cannot be fully interpreted. There is some kind of built-in undecidability in the quantum world...

Comment: After some more thoughts, it is not that easy to build some kind of deductive systems with a three valued logic. If (U=>U is U) and (T and U is U)  , modus ponens is not a tautology anymore... Which rules of inference can we use?